# 2nd Monitor Freezes every 10 seconds

Tags: desktop-computer

I have two monitor (both plasma) set up right now, one through HDMI and the other VGA.

Every time I would play games on the hdmi one, the vga TV will freeze every 30 seconds. Any solutions?

I have upped my ram to 12gb and also update all the drivers and window updates already.

I replaced it with an LCD monitor and it works fine. But I really like my 2nd monitor to be a plasma (makes videos look really good).

I also lowering the resolution on the 2nd screen but did not do the trick.

Running out of ideas.

Running computer on windows 10
Don't remember the graphic card (at work) but its definitely not faulty because I play online games on it.